# pocketsphinx how to determine out of grammar words

Tags: cmusphinx

I am currently using pocketsphix demo (android and visual studio 2010) and I have configured a jsgf grammer
like this

```
 #JSGF V1.0;
 grammar Names;
 public <popular> = muhammad | ahmed | maria | john | kelley | peter | jacob | jason;
```

Whenever I say correct name, it detects it right in most cases but when I say a name not in the list, it still matches something and I do not want that or atleast be able to detect if something was said that was not in Grammar (may be through some score or api of pocketsphinx)

I am sure pocketsphinx has it somewhere which I don't know. Please advise.

Thanks, 
Ahmed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this feature is not implemented. For more details see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qcan_pocketsphinx_reject_out-of-grammar_words_and_noises

You can use keyword spotting mode instead to look for a list of keyphrases. You can configure activation threshold for every phrase.